# What's the best RPC package to write a C++ client/server for a peer-to-peer system?

Tags: c++, xml-rpc, rpc, protocol-buffers

I have a program that performs compute-heavy local processing. The compute packages have 16MiB input buffers and generate between 10KB and 16MiB of output. This all happens in a multi-threaded environment.

I have a number of users who are compute-bound. I'm interested in adding support for peer-to-peer multiprocessing. That is, clients would be run on multiple computers in the organization. The master would find available clients, send them 16MiB buffers, and then get the results.

The master will have a list of available clients. It will then send a message to each client that it is free. The clients will start a thread for each core that they have. Each thread will ask the master for a work buffer, will compute the results, and will then send the results to the master. The master will incorporate the results from each client into the final output.

A typical run involves crunching between 100 and 50,000 16MiB buffers. The output is typically in the 100MB to 10GB range. There are no data dependencies between the buffers.

I'm looking for the best way to arrange the communications between the client and the server. My plan is to use some kind of RPC. I do not want to embed a web server in either the client or the server. Instead, my plan is to simply receive connections on a TCP socket and have some kind of basic RPC.

Here are the options I'm considering:

1. I can role my own client/server system and use protocol buffers to put the whole thing together.
2. I could use one of the existing [RPC systems for potocol buffers](http://code.google.com/p/protobuf/wiki/ThirdPartyAddOns#RPC_Implementations).
3. I could embed a web server and use XMLRPC.

The implementation language is C++. The program compiles for Linux, MacOS, and with mingw for Windows.

Thanks.

Comment: What's your question?  Anyway, `protobuf` is a good choice for C++ coding, XML is a bad one.  RPC is a (potential) security hole.  Just include a field in your message representing "what kind of processing should be done" instead of trying to pass a function name to be looked up on the remote end.

Comment: Also, since this is a large amount of data to be transferred, you may want to serialize transfers to a multi-threaded client, so that one thread can start working while the remaining work items transfer, instead of splitting your bandwidth among several items.

Comment: My question is "What's the best RPC package to write a C++ client/server for a peer-to-peer system?"

Comment: And yes, my client is multi-threaded. Very multi-threaded. One thread per core.

Comment: The question indicated that it's multi-threaded.  Why is there one thread per core?  Because that way they don't fight for CPU resources.  And that makes good sense for the computation part of the task.  But for the download part, there should be only one thread per network connection (i.e. just one thread allowed to download at once), or else they will fight for network resources and slow each others' transfers down.

Comment: There are lots of ways to structure the client/server, including one thread per tcp connection, one thread for all of the tcp connections with an event-handler, etc. Also, if the network transit time is a small fraction of the CPU time, then the content is irrelevant. I gather you don't have a recommendation?

Comment: I gave my recommendation in the first comment: Google protobuf.

Comment: protobuf is a serialization system, not an RPC mechanism. There are multiple RPC systems that use protobufs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We found that [0MQ](http://zeromq.org/) met our criteria.